# Prevent winjs application from crashing when file call not succesfull

Tags: error-handling, windows-8.1, winjs, windows

I'm currently working on a Windows 8.1 App for tablets. I want to call an xls file from the users drive on click. The problem is that the code I have so far does not prevent the App from crashing in case the file cannot be found. I need some kind of error handling that simply prevents that from happening and sends an alert or something.

Here is what I have so far

```
        var me = this;
    var fileName = "ReportCall.xls";
    var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
    var reportFile = localFolder.getFileAsync("Attachments\\Reports\\fileName");
    var file = local.Folder.getFileAsync(fileName);

    reportFile.done(function(file) {
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).done(
    function (success) {
    if (success) {
        // DO NOTHING
    } else {
        //Alert. File not found!
    }
    });
    });
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean in the first getFileAsync call to have the argument be "Attachment\\Reports\\" + filename, instead of using "filename" as the name of the file itself? As written, your code is not looking for ReportCall.xls. Also, your next line uses local.Folder instead of localFolder, so I don't see how that would work--looks like a typo.

Comment: Yes, youre right. Both are typos. Thanks for the info. Any idea how to make  the error handling work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem with the following code

```
var me = this;
var fileName = "ReportCall.xls";
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
var file = localFolder.getFileAsync(fileName):

localFolder.getFileAsync("Attachments\\Reports + fileName").then(function)(file {
},function(e) {
    alert("file cannot be found");
});
```